# How to add tab animation on change in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I want to add navigate forward and backward animation on tab switches.

I want to replicate the current state of Facebook's app tab navigation animations.

I have currently tried adding a method onto the individual tab to call a function that calls navigate forward.

```
<ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
  <ion-tab-button (click)="goToListTab()" mode="md">
    <ion-icon name="list"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>Orders</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>

  <ion-tab-button (click)="goToNewTab()" mode="md">
    <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>New Order</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>

  <ion-tab-button (click)="goToAccountTab()" mode="md">
    <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>Account</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>
</ion-tab-bar>
```

and my .ts file has the functions that call navigate. I included only one to simplify.

```
goToAccountTab() {
    this.router.navigateBack('/tabs/account');
}
```

On goToAccountTab I expected it to navigate to the account tab with the navigateBack animation, but it successfully goes to the account tab but does not perform the navigateBack animation.

Answer (score 1):

the way ionic does that is by using the [native page transitions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions) plugins which is **[no longer maintained](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions)** and you got a bug that I wasn't able to fix (when doing the animation, you see twice the pages) but it's the best solution I found until know, since Ionic didn't do it properly (for the moment).

So, I let the code here, it's could help and maybe you'll found the fix ;)

1. Run

```
ionic cordova plugin add com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions
npm install @ionic-native/native-page-transitions
```

2. Import into the app.module.ts

```
import { NativePageTransitions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/ngx'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativePageTransitions,
  ]
}
```

3. add to your tabs.page.ts the animation logic

```
import {
  NativePageTransitions,
  NativeTransitionOptions,
} from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/ngx'

export class TabsPage {
loaded: boolean = false
tabIndex: number = 0

constructor(private nativePageTransitions: NativePageTransitions) {

  //Look the index to see which direction to go (if you have more than 3 tabs)
  private getAnimationDirection(e: any): string {
    var currentIndex = this.tabIndex

    this.tabIndex = e.index
    // or 
    // this.tabIndex = Object.keys(this.tabs).indexOf(e.tab)

    switch (true) {
      case currentIndex < e.index:
        return 'left'
      case currentIndex > e.index:
        return 'right'
    }
  }

  transition(e: any): void {
    let options: NativeTransitionOptions = {
      direction: this.getAnimationDirection(e),
      duration: 250,
      slowdownfactor: -1,
      slidePixels: 0,
      iosdelay: 20,
      androiddelay: 0,
      fixedPixelsTop: 0,
      fixedPixelsBottom: 48,
    }

    if (!this.loaded) {
      this.loaded = true
      return
    }

    this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options)
  }
}
```

4. and inside the tabs.page.html

```
<ion-tabs (ionTabsWillChange)="transition($event)">
 /*...*/
</ion-tabs>
```

*note:

1. for me, $event gave me back an object like that `{tab: 'home'}`, since I was creating the tabs with a loop trough an array of tabs, i could find the index with `Object.keys(tabs).indexOf($event.tab)`

2. I also tried to use a simple angular route animation, but since ionic wrap the logic inside the ion-tabs, it doesn't seems to work*

Answer (score 0):

Using Ionic v4, I was unable to get the index from the tab controller, but I solved this by keeping a list object of my tabs and getting the numeric index that way.

package.json

```
"@ionic/angular": "^4.9.1"
"@angular/core": "^8.2.7"
"com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": "^0.6.5",
```

Tabs.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { IonTabs } from '@ionic/angular';

import {
  NativePageTransitions,
  NativeTransitionOptions,
} from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/ngx';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tabs.page.scss']
})
export class TabsPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('navTabs', { static: false }) navTabs: IonTabs;

  private tabs = {
    events: 0,
    notifications: 1,
    profile: 2
  };
  loaded = false;
  tabIndex = 0;

  constructor(
    private nativePageTransitions: NativePageTransitions
  ) { }

  private getAnimationDirection(e: any): string {

    const currentIndex = this.tabIndex;
    this.tabIndex = this.tabs[e.tab];

    switch (true) {
      case currentIndex > this.tabs[e.tab]:
        return 'left';
      case currentIndex < this.tabs[e.tab]:
        return 'right';
    }
  }

  transition(e: any): void {

    const options: NativeTransitionOptions = {
      direction: this.getAnimationDirection(e),
      duration: 250,
      slowdownfactor: -1,
      slidePixels: 0,
      iosdelay: 20,
      androiddelay: 0,
      fixedPixelsTop: 0,
      fixedPixelsBottom: 48,
    };

    if (!this.loaded) {
      this.loaded = true;
      return;
    }

    this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options);
  }

}
```

Tabs.html

```html
<ion-tabs #navTabs (ionTabsWillChange)="transition($event)">

  <ion-tab-bar color="dark" slot="bottom">

    <ion-tab-button tab="events">
      <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Events</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="notifications">
      <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Notification</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="profile">
      <ion-icon name="barcode"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to make that animations.

It is an animation that plays with the ionic classes, without the need to install anything.

In your components:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  componentElement: HTMLElement;

  constructor(
    private nativeComponent: ElementRef
  ) {
    this.componentElement = this.nativeComponent.nativeElement;
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and another component:

```
export class NotificationsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  componentElement: HTMLElement;

  constructor(
    private nativeComponent: ElementRef
  ) {
    this.componentElement = this.nativeComponent.nativeElement;
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Next, in your tabs routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule),
        data: {
          index: 0
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: () => import('./notifications/notifications.module').then(m => m.notificationsPageModule),
        data: {
          index: 1
        }
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

Next, in your tabs page:

```
export class TabsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('tabs', { static: true }) tabs: IonTabs;
  routerOutletTabs: IonRouterOutlet;

  last_component: HTMLElement;
  last_component_index: number;

  constructor() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.routerOutletTabs = this.tabs.outlet;


    this.routerOutletTabs.activateEvents.subscribe((e: any) => {
      if(!this.last_component){
        this.last_component = e.componentElement;
      this.last_component_index = this.routerOutletTabs.activatedRouteData.index;
        return;
      }

      const data_router = this.routerOutletTabs.activatedRouteData;

      if(this.last_component_index < data_router.index){
        this.last_component.classList.add('toLeft');
        this.last_component.classList.remove('toRight');

        e.componentElement.classList.add('toLeft');
        e.componentElement.classList.remove('toRight');
      }else{
        this.last_component.classList.remove('toLeft');
        this.last_component.classList.add('toRight');

        e.componentElement.classList.remove('toLeft');
        e.componentElement.classList.add('toRight');
      }

      this.last_component = e.componentElement;
      this.last_component_index = data_router.index;
    })
  }
}
```

tabs.page.html

```
  <ion-tabs #tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button tab="home">
        <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
      </ion-tab-button>
      <ion-tab-button tab="notifications">
        <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
```

and finally, in your global style file:

```
ion-router-outlet[tabs=true] > .ion-page {
  --velocity-transition: 0.2s;
}

ion-router-outlet[tabs=true] > .ion-page.toRight:not(.ion-page-hidden) {
  animation: route_enter_right var(--velocity-transition) ease forwards;
}

ion-router-outlet[tabs=true] > .ion-page.toLeft:not(.ion-page-hidden) {
  animation: route_enter_left var(--velocity-transition) ease forwards;
}

ion-router-outlet[tabs=true] > .ion-page.ion-page-hidden.toLeft {
  animation: route_leave_left var(--velocity-transition) ease forwards;
  display: flex !important;
}

ion-router-outlet[tabs=true] > .ion-page.ion-page-hidden.toRight {
  animation: route_leave_right var(--velocity-transition) ease forwards;
  display: flex !important;
}

@keyframes route_enter_left {
  from{
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  to{
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes route_enter_right {
  from{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to{
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes route_leave_left {
  from{
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes route_leave_right {
  from{
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to{
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

This works for me and I don't need to add packages to my project.